# Embed Telnet Control in Webpage

Tags: javascript, telnet

I was wondering if there are any Telnet "controls" that can be embedded into a web page (more specifically, a ASP.NET MVC page). I'd prefer not to use an ActiveX control, but I am open to any suggestions (a Javascript solution would be ideal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at [Anyterm](http://anyterm.org/index.html) for a potential Javascript solution. There's also [FMud](http://bc-dev.net/projects/fmud/) if you're willing to go flash.

I don't think that either of these have a way for a user to specify where they want to connect to (you pre-configure them before embedding), but if you don't need that functionality, they both work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Anyterm could be a great solution. I also hadn't considered Flash/Silverlight options. Thanks again!